# RAILS 3.2: How to rescue from "Routing Error" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

How to rescue from `RoutingError` in Rails 3.2 applications such as redirecting to `root_path`?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no circumstances when you would want to rescue from a RoutingError.

If you want all routes not otherwise specified to redirect to some particular action (for custom 'not found' errors, for instance), you can make the last route in your `routes.rb` file match anything and point there:

```
match "*path" => 'some_controller#some_action'
```

Routes are tried in order and the first one which matches is used, so as long as this remains last, it will be used if and only if no other route matches the requested path.

Comment: Your first sentence is not relevant to the question / answer. You could have asked in a comment why smileyUser would want to do this. What comes after your first sentence is helpful though.